# ¿Como saber columna pulsada en un GridView en ASP?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un GridView en asp del cual querria saber el nombre o número de columna que ha pulsado. No me interesa la fila ya que eso ya lo gestiono, quiero que pueda pulsar sobre el header de una columna y a partir de ahí disparar una función para hacer algo.

Aprovechando el mismo hilo tambien quiero saber si pulsa sobre una celda concreta saber cual ha pulsado y tambien disparar una funcion.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu DataGrid, si etas utilizando ASPX con Forms; dentro del control tambien manejan eventos; Para tu requerimiento seria el evento : RowCommand
             [e.Row.RowIndex]

```
    protected void TUDATAGRID_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "TOTAL") //EVALÚAS QUE LA COLUMNA TOTAL  
            {
                  //ACCIONES QUE DESEAS REALIZAR SI HACEN CLICK EN ESA COLUMNA
            }

            if (e.CommandName == "Entrada") //EVALÚAS QUE LA COLUMNA QUE DESEAS  
            {
                  //ACCIONES QUE DESEAS REALIZAR EN OTRA COLUMNA 
            }
}
```

Funciona de la Siguiente Manera al hacer Click en uan Fila_Persona automaticamente obtienes el numero de Fila que hizo Click con e. ahora lo que realizas en cada IF es elvaluar a e. Tambien para saber si hizo Click en la Columna que tu quieres ... !!! Te dejo una Captura de como lo Tengo Implementado ..

https://ibb.co/dcHG37

Comment: Gracias @Anyel pero esto no es lo que busco, el rowcomand ya lo gestiono pero en mi caso quiero saber en que columna pulsa independientemente del rowcomand imaginate que tengo un gridview compuesto de filas personas y columnas totalventas cada mes y quiero saber si pulsa en que columna de mes pulsa para disparar una acción.

Comment: Puedes poner una captura de pantalla de tu grid ?

Comment: Te modifique la Respuesta, revisa la Imagen estoy seguro de que es el que necesitas .. si no me avisas .